# sql case statement with string+id as a return

Tags: sql, mariadb

So I have this query and wanted to implement some HTML into this, so I just can print is on my website without using loops. But my problem here is that the string part of my cases isn't attached to the `testresults.TestCaseId`? How can I do that?

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN testresults.StatusId = 1 THEN  '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">'+testresults.TestCaseId+'</li>' ELSE '' END
FROM
    testresults
ORDER BY testresults.TestRunsId DESC;
```

This query returns only the value of testresults.TestCaseId, and not 'this'+...+'this' part.

Comment: You should use `concat` to join strings.

Comment: `+` is for string concatenation on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

MariaDB/MySQL do not use `+` as the string concatenation operator.  Instead, use the `CONCAT()` function:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN testresults.StatusId = 1
         THEN CONCAT('<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">',
                     testresults.TestCaseId, '</li>')
         ELSE '' END
FROM testresults
ORDER BY TestRunsId DESC;
```

If you wanted to use an actual operator here, then you might be able to use the ANSI `||` concatenation operator, depending on your MariaDB server mode:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN testresults.StatusId = 1
         THEN '<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">' ||
              testresults.TestCaseId || '</li>'
         ELSE '' END
FROM testresults
ORDER BY TestRunsId DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, did not know this, I'm new to sql